# JavaScript is only working on the actual table page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

if i select an entry from the table the value is displayed on the button, **but** when i change to another table page it´s not working anymore. If i now **refresh** the html page only this table page is working.

What must i change so that i could change the table page and select an entry to be displayed?

Here is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>TITLE</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css"> <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"> <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"> <!-- Table  -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>    
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script> <!-- Table  -->
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script> <!-- Table  -->

    <style type="text/css">  
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
        }       
        #wrap {
            min-height: 100%;
        }       
        #main {
            overflow:auto;
            padding-bottom:80px; /* this needs to be bigger than footer height*/
        }       
        .footer {
            position: relative;
            text-align: center;
            margin-top: -80px; /* negative value of footer height */
            height: 80px;
            clear:both;
            padding-top:20px;
        }   
        .loginwidth {
            width:300px;
        }       
    </style>    
</head> 

  <body role="document">

    <div id="wrap">
    <div id="main" class="container theme-showcase" role="main">

    <div class="row-fluid"> 
    <br><br><br><br>    </div> <!-- row -->

    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="page-header">
            <h1>DELETE</h1>
            <p><button id="usrButton" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" style="width: 400px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> EMail <b><span id="id_username"></span></b> Delete</button></p>
            <p><button id="nrButton"type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" style="width: 400px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> NR <b><span id="nr_number"></span></b> Delete</button></p>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- row -->

    <div class="row-fluid">     
        <table id="datatable" class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>User ID</th>
            <th>EMail</th>
            <th>Number</th>
            <th>NR</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>23</td>
<td>OnE@trashmail.com</td>
<td>4252413214</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>22</td>
<td>Two@trashmail.com</td>
<td>7089174804</td>
<td>01234000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>21</td>
<td>Three@trashmail.com</td>
<td>3682199489</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>20</td>
<td>4u@trashmail.com</td>
<td>3041695348</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>19</td>
<td>Inf0@trashmail.com</td>
<td>4831983349</td>
<td>01826718</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2</td>
<td>notMe@trashmail.com</td>
<td>1179394945</td>
<td>02050039</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>14</td>
<td>Test@trashmail.com</td>
<td>0265164918</td>
<td>01824010</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>24</td>
<td>what@trashmail.com</td>
<td>4016411332</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>10</td>
<td>SiX@trashmail.com</td>
<td>2124149389</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>12</td>
<td>Seven@trashmail.com</td>
<td>0113254286</td>
<td>01825638</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>15</td>
<td>world@trashmail.com</td>
<td>1053223407</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>30</td>
<td>button@trashmail.com</td>
<td>1059923407</td>
<td>0815</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>40</td>
<td>go@trashmail.com</td>
<td>25412545</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
        </table>
    </div> <!-- row -->

    </div> <!-- main -->
    </div> <!-- wrap -->    

        <div class="footer">
        <p><h4 class="text-center">Copyright © <small>2015</small></h4></p>
    </div>  

<script>    
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var email = ""; 
        var nr = "";

        $('#usrButton').prop('disabled', true);
        $('#nrButton').prop('disabled', true);
        //----------------------------------------------------          
        $('#datatable').DataTable( {
            stateSave: true,            
            scrollY: "350px",
            paging: true
        } );
        //----------------------------------------------------  
        $('#datatable tr').click(function() {
            email = $(this).find("td").eq(1).html(); 
            nr = $(this).find("td").eq(3).html(); 

            $('#id_username').html(email);
            $('#nr_number').html(nr);

            $('#usrButton').prop('disabled', email.trim() == "");
            $('#nrButton').prop('disabled', nr.trim() == "");
        });
        //----------------------------------------------------  
    });
</script>

  </body>   
</html>
```

I also tried to insert this code in jsfiddle but it´s not working correct ???
http://jsfiddle.net/rule_34/t0eszv7w/

Comment: Your fiddle says that DataTable is not a function, please check if everything is correct.

Comment: **[Here is the updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/t0eszv7w/1/)** for anyone who wants to try..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/t0eszv7w/2/)**

You need event delegation here since when you move the next page `tr`s are constructed and added dynamically. So you need to change your code as below:

```
$(document).on('click','#datatable tr',function () {
    email = $(this).find("td").eq(1).html();
    nr = $(this).find("td").eq(3).html();

    $('#id_username').html(email);
    $('#nr_number').html(nr);

    $('#usrButton').prop('disabled', email.trim() == "");
    $('#nrButton').prop('disabled', nr.trim() == "");
});
```

**UPDATE**

For better performance instead of attaching event through document you can directly add it to `table`, since `tr` rests inside `table` and table will be `static`

```
$("#datatable").on('click','tr',function () {
    email = $(this).find("td").eq(1).html();
    nr = $(this).find("td").eq(3).html();

    $('#id_username').html(email);
    $('#nr_number').html(nr);

    $('#usrButton').prop('disabled', email.trim() == "");
    $('#nrButton').prop('disabled', nr.trim() == "");
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/t0eszv7w/3/)**

Comment: Anytime.. Happy coding.. :)